# How to store data using s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to aws and I want to integrate IAM in my aws account.
I have gone through this link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQheV84Ae40&list=PL_OdF9Z6GmVZCwyfd8n6_50jcE_Xlz1je&index=3
but not getting the proper idea.
Is there any example for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IAM to create **Users** in your AWS Account.

You can then associate **policies** with those users, which grant them permission to use particular AWS services, such as Amazon S3. IAM is automatically integrated with *every* AWS service.

See: [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Answer (score 0):

IAM service in AWS is used for user management, that helps you securely control access to AWS resources. In IAM you can create users and you can assign roles to the users based on your needs. you can create custom policies also, AWS provides many custom policies by default once go through Its mostly self-explanatory.